# Keydownevent in fullscreen with FullScreen API

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, google-chrome, fullscreen

I use the JavaScript FullScreen API and jQuery in chrome and firefox. I want to stop keydownevent bubbling, because i don't want that user left fullscreen mode with hotkeys (F11 and Ecs). But callback in chrome doesn't call and callback in firefox call for F11 ,but not call for Esc. Why is this happening?

```
$(document).bind({
    'keydown': function (e) {
        alert('It works!');
        if (e.which == 122 || e.which == 27) {
             alert('F11 or Esc');
             return false;
        }
});

var docElm = document.getElementById('gallery');
if (docElm.mozRequestFullScreen) {
     docElm.mozRequestFullScreen();
}
else if (docElm.webkitRequestFullScreen) {
     docElm.webkitRequestFullScreen(Element.ALLOW_KEYBOARD_INPUT);
}
```

Comment: It would be bad if you could prevent the user from doing that.

Comment: I know that, but my customer thinks differently.

Comment: Maybe you could steal the key presses (but not mouse clicks) into a Flash frame.

Comment: Any chance of installing extra software to the target machine? Then it's relatively easy.

Comment: I am developing asp.net mvc 4 project.

Comment: I mean, if it's for a kiosk application, then you could install AutoHotKey to the kiosk to kill some keys.

Answer (score 0):

It's happening because it's a built-in security method, which browser vendors have hard-coded expressly for the purpose of preventing the exact thing your client wants to do:  keep people from leaving.

Personally, I wish that `esc` was available for use as a button to bring up the menu of a fullscreen game (seeing as that's what it's done for years), but that's not an option, currently.

Of course, you could then listen for the exit-fullscreen, and after that bring up the game menu (which is weird), but otherwise, affiliate-marketers would just stuff you on full-page ads, make them full-screen, and provide no exit button, aside from closing the browser (which you couldn't do without using the keyboard, which Fullscreen could ALSO prevent).

Comment: Now, I have come to the same conclusion. But youtube (html5 player) such as somehow doing it. The user will have the right to choose full screen and normal mode. Ability to exit full screen mode by pressing the key breaks the application logic.

Comment: Where is the HTML5 version of YouTube's full-screen doing it? `esc` works fine for me, while I'm fullscreen in an HTML5 window.